# Javascript form validation submit errors

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

From everything I've seen around the net, it appears that the following code should do the following (and this is my expectation):

- If the email ("aid") does not match the regex, show alert message and return false
- If the password ("pass") is blank, show alert message and return false
- If both conditions pass validation submit the form

The Javascript is as follows:

```
function validate() {
var email = document.getElementById('aid').value;
var pass = document.getElementById('apw').value;        
var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;  
if (!emailPattern.test(email)) {
    alert("Not a valid email address");
    return false;
}
if (pass == null || pass == "") {
    alert("Password is blank");
    return false;   
}
return true;
}
```

The opening for tag is as follows:

```
<form action="choose.php" onsubmit="validate();" method="post">
```

The problem I'm having is that when the submit button is clicked, the alert message will pop up, but then choose.php is loaded in the browser.  I want the script, if the error conditions are triggered, to remain on the page until both conditions are passed.

Comment: Side note, here's a better RegEx for ya: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: There are valid e–mail addresses that will fail the e–mail test. Better to just let users enter whatever they want and test it by sending an e–mail. Oh, and the function doesn't have to return `true`, any value other than `false` will let the form submit.

Comment: I'm aware of the shortcomings with the above RegEx (and using RegEx to validate email in general), but these aren't really concerns for this project.  Thanks for the links/input though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your onSubmit to `onSubmit="return validate();"`. This way when it returns false, the form doesn't get submitted. Right now it just calls the validate() function and continues on with submitting the form