# Form submitting with errors

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I have a form, and I've written a validation script for it, however, it's not working 100%. It outputs errors fine, but the submit button will submit the form, even if it has outputted the alert boxes. Anyone have any idea why?

Apparently not all the code pasted. I would just use the Required parameter, but I need JS validation as it is an assignment. Also, UL is defined before this part of code, as there is a list before this.

HTML:

```
<div class = "form">
        <form name = "contactForm" onsubmit="validateForm()" action = "form.php">

        <li><label>First name: </label><input type = "text" name = "fname" autofocus></li>

        <li><label>Last Name: </label><input type = "text" name = "lname"></li>

        <li><label>Email: </label><input type = "text" name = "email"> <button onclick = "validateEmail();return false">Check if email is valid</button> </li>

        <li><label>Message: </label> <br>

            <textarea rows = "10" cols = "50" name = "message"></textarea></li>

        <li> <input type = "submit"> </li>

        </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm()
{
  var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["fname"].value; //Gets the form and field name from the HTML

  if (x==null || x=="") //If the field "fname" contains null, or nothing, then output an alert telling the user to input something into the field. Same goes for the rest of the code.
  {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }

  var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["lname"].value;

  if (x==null || x=="") 
  {
    alert("Last name must be filled out");
    return false; 
  }

  var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["email"].value;

  var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/; 

  if(reg.test(x) == false)
  {
      alert("Please enter a valid Email");
      return false;
  }

  if (x==null || x=="")
  {
    alert("Email must be filled out");
    return false;
  }

  var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["message"].value;

  if (x==null || x=="")
  {
    alert("Message must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript form validation submit errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595460/javascript-form-validation-submit-errors)

Comment: at least have a fiddle created before posting questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your html:

```
    <form name = "contactForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action = "form.php">
```

You have to add keyword **return** before your ValidateForm() function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything telling it NOT to submit the form.  The "return false" just sends the message back.  You need to get rid of that OnSubmit tag, and call the function from onClick from your Submit button.  Then only if it returns TRUE, do the form submit.